# Django url not matching in production

Tags: django, regex, django-urls, wsgi, pythonanywhere

I have a web app which uses Django4.0.6 and Python3.9.

```
urlpatterns += [
    re_path(r'^payment/payment-history/(?P<cand_id>\d+)/(?P<curr_year>\d+)/(?:/(?P<payment_id>-?\d+))?/(?:/(?P<is_email_sent>\d+))?/?$',
            views.payment_history,
            name='payment_history')
]
```

I have this regex which works fine when I run my code on my machine using Django runserver command.

URL I am trying to match is `https://something.com/tenant/payment/payment-history/9299/2023//`

I deployed the webapp on Python anywhere and suddenly this url patterns don't match.

So I did some debugging and found that on production the url that it tries to match is `https://something.com/tenant/payment/payment-history/9299/2023/`. It ignores the empty part of the url `//`.

I tried to change the regex to

```
urlpatterns += [
    re_path(r'^payment/payment-history/(?P<cand_id>\d+)/(?P<curr_year>\d+)/(?:/(?P<payment_id>-?\d+))?/?(?:/(?P<is_email_sent>\d+))?/?$',
            views.payment_history,
            name='payment_history')
]
```

The pattern matches but it breaks the feature. Is it possible to force url to match with the empty part of it.

Comment: URL patterns work like a funnel, if first pattern did not match an URL the next one will be applied and so on. You can simplify the pattern by splitting it into multiple patterns from more specific/detailed to less specific.